# React.js: Unable to get the promise results set in the properties inside the array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, promise

The `api response` consisting of properties such as `films` and `vehicles` array of urls and by `fetching those`, I'm trying to get the `resultant objects` and trying to update it back inside those mentioned properties.

After returning the promises using `Promise.all`, I'm trying to set the `films` and `vehicles` with the results, but I'm unable to get the desired output. Here's my [**Working Code Link**](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-react-promises-fclt8s?file=/src/components/ToDo.js)

Any help regarding the problem would be appreciated.

I'm getting the below issue after setting `films` and `vehicles` in the response objects after waiting for promises to get the results:

[image]

Here in this case, I'm getting the `films` first but `not with the desired output` where the `films needs to the array of objects`, but instead `getting the promise status`.

[image]

Next, I'm getting the `films` result as `pending` and `vehicles` promise `fulfilled` result instead of the resultant array of objects in the mentioned object properties.

How to reolve this issue? My one only `desired output is to get the films and vehicles array of objects inside the response object which I have kept in the newState`.

Please find my code below:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const url = `https://swapi.dev/api/people/`;

export function ToDo() {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    apiCallHandler(url);
  }, []);

  async function asyncAllPromises(arr) {
    const promises = await arr.map(async (item) => {
      const response = await fetch(item, { cache: "no-cache" });
      const json = await response.json();
      return json;
    });
    const response = await Promise.all(promises);
    return response;
  }

  const apiCallHandler = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      let data = await response.json();

      let newState = data.results.map((result) => {
        result.films = asyncAllPromises(result.films).then((data) => data);
        result.vehicles = asyncAllPromises(result.vehicles).then(
          (data) => data
        );
        return result;
      });

      setResults(newState);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Unable to find data", error);
    }
  };

  console.log("results", results);

  const table =
    results && results.length ? (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Mass</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {results.map((result, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{result.name}</td>
                <td>{result.mass}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    ) : (
      "Loading.."
    );

  return <>{table}</>;
}
```

Comment: Does https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-react-promises-forked-yrj3k3?file=/src/components/ToDo.js fix the issue for you?

Comment: @RobinThomas Thanks for the try. But I'm still getting the promise status as pending inside `films` and `vehicles` instead of the resulting arrays of objects.

Comment: The accepted answer is same as the one in the codesandbox I shared. So I assume mine is working?

Comment: No @RobinThomas, It wasn't the same. You missed waiting for and resolving all the promises in line 27.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Had shared the wrong codesandbox url :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call `await` in lines 27 and 28, so `result.films` is kept as a `Promise`. In addition, the `.then(data=>data)` is redundant.

Therefore, the definition of newState should be changed to:

```
let newState = await Promise.all(data.results.map(async result => {
  result.films = await asyncAllPromises(result.films).then((data) => data);
  result.vehicles = await asyncAllPromises(result.vehicles);
  return result;
}));
```

The `Promise.all()` is used to convert the `Promise`s returned by the `async` mapper function back into one `Promise` which is then `await`ed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was missing and it resolved my issue. I needed to wait for the two promises arr to resolve and also needed to wait for the map to resolve the promises.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because of how `newState` is calculated

```
let newState = data.results.map((result) => {
  result.films = asyncAllPromises(result.films).then((data) => data);
  result.vehicles = asyncAllPromises(result.vehicles).then(
    (data) => data
  );
  return result;
});
```

Since `asyncAllPromises` is returning a `Promise`, you need to wait for it. Second, `map` will be returning a `Promise`. You so need to wait for it as well.

You can fix this issue by:

```
let newState = await Promise.all(data.results.map(async (result) => {
  result.films = await asyncAllPromises(result.films)
  result.vehicles = await asyncAllPromises(result.vehicles);
  return result;
}));
```